# Ubuntu 8 + Firefox 3.6 + Flash: DIV Overlay Problem

Tags: css, flash, html, overlay

**Situation:** Got a flash object with an icon bar (div with pngs) on top of it. Works on all browsers except Firefox 3.6 on Ubuntu 8. Example: http://ListAndPlay.com

**Problem:** Icons suddenly disappear after the flash is being loaded. See this screenshot: http://api.browsershots.org/png/512/e3/e30de0b1ad995fa1aa9c14cbc19fb43c.png

**What I've tried:**  Setting z-index, recoding the JQuery behind it, nothing works.

I'm very curious what I did wrong and how you would fix this issue :)

Comment: Hi there:

I can report that this issue exists in Firefox 3.6.x on WinXP. I included wmode=opaque, with no change. the Flash content hides all other elements regardless of stacking order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set wmode to opaque.

```
<object height="100%" width="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="ytPlayer" data="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer" style="height: 286px; width: 1280px;"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"></object>
```

Comment: Hi Dave! Thnx for your reaction, changed it to opaque and still problem with firefox 3.5 on ubuntu: http://api.browsershots.org/png/512/d9/d919d9da3b667718c54e9f1b8bc7adde.png

Comment: Hi MeProtozoan, well, I think I didn't got it right. Anyway I think http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html can help you. Or maybe a combo solution, setting wmode to opaque or transparent (whatever you need), and setting HTML (raw or generated) z-index through CSS. Let me know your findings. I rememeber I had a issue with flash opacity a few months ago.

Comment: Thnx a lot Dave, that explains it all. It seems to occur only with old flash versions, the newest seems to solve it :) (my test Ubuntu was running flash 9)